# Can I undo marking a comment as a "great comment"?

Tags: support, comments

Just fully trusting what was written there, I marked Joseph's first comment on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4828/a-stacktrace-for-errors/4837#4837) answer as a "great comment". Now Ulrike's comment told me that the first comment wasn't that great after all (no offense meant ;-). How can I get rid of this upvote?

Comment: You can't undo, but you don't need to worry about it too much, either.

Comment: @Jukka: It's not that I really worry; it would just be nicer if one could undo this. What a pity.

Comment: You can’t undo answer/question votes either.

Comment: @Caramdir: you can if the question/answer was edited.  Hendrik, I think that's one case where we just have to admit that the software isn't quite as perfect as we might like ...

Comment: @Andrew: OK, if I have to, then I'll admit! Thanks for the clarification about questions/answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to undo comment votes at this time.

edit: this is now possible, but only once, and only within a limited time window after comment upvoting. Sorry, I thought the latter part was obvious, but maybe not :)

Comment: Even if sometimes I'm not happy with this answer, it's definitely correct `:-)`

Comment: Is there a time in the future when this will become a feature?

Comment: @werner this is now possible

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Thanks; great news! And also for still being active around here...

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Is this already active? If it is, do I just click the upvote button again? If that's how to do it, it's not working for me.

Comment: This does not seem to work under Google Chrome 21.0.1180.79 (supporting @ Jake's comment from last month).

Comment: @werner no repro. I just upvoted and un-upvoted Jake's comment here fine. With Chrome latest, etc

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Agreed. I just up-voted your comment here and could remove it. Similarly on something on the main site. Is there a time limit on this? Like the original 5-minute up/down-vote thing for regular posts? That was not mentioned anywhere on this post, so I don't know.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I indeed assumed that there would be no time constraint on the un-upvoting. The way the feature is implemented now (with the time constraint) doesn't really help in the case that the reason for the upvote becomes invalid after a while. Standard example would be a comment "You'll need to tell us how you X the Y, otherwise we can't help.", which I'd upvote, then the OP tells us how they X the Y, and then I'd want to remove my upvote to be able to flag as obsolete.

Comment: @jake in that case the feature-request is to be able to flag a comment you upvoted.